# Styling checkboxes rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I'm trying to style checkboxes in my rails app.

```
<div class="form-group">
     <%= f.label :tag_list %>
   <p>Science</p>
  <%= f.check_box :tag_list, { :multiple => true }, 'science', nil %>

  <p>Math</p>
  <%= f.check_box :tag_list, { :multiple => true }, 'math', nil %>

  </div>
```

In my application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui/button
//= require jquery-ui/datepicker
//= require jquery-ui/slider
//= require jquery-ui/spinner
//= require jquery-ui/tooltip
//= require jquery-ui/effect
//= require flatuipro
//= require flat-ui.min
//= require sweet-alert-confirm
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .

$(':checkbox').radiocheck();
```

I'm using something [called flat-ui](http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/docs/components.html#fui-checkbox) and am trying to apply the styles they provide for check boxes. **How do I do this?**

Comment: what class do you want to add ?

Comment: After all required parameters you can add as much html attributes as you want, so just add `class: 'bla blah'` at the end and it would work

Comment: @Katie, you need to add the js file and bind rediocheck with checkbox.

Comment: @Katie, you need the radiocheck.js file to be included.

Comment: I did this, i'm no longer getting any javascript errors in the console, but the form still does not look stylized, please see the discussion: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71404/discussion-between-jon-and-katie-h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation, it seems like the class `checkbox` needs to be given to the `label`, and the `input` needs to be inside the `label`. Your markup would then look something like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :tag_list, class: 'checkbox' do %>
    <p>Science</p>
    <%= f.check_box :tag_list, { multiple: true }, 'science', nil %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Then, make sure you are calling `$(':checkbox').radiocheck();` in your JavaScript, and that you have included the Flat-UI js file.

**Update from [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71404/discussion-between-jon-and-katie-h)**:

Make sure that each `input` has its own `label`:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :tag_list, class: 'checkbox' do %>
    <p>Science</p>
    <%= f.check_box :tag_list, { multiple: true }, 'science', nil %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.label :tag_list, class: 'checkbox' do %>
    <p>Math</p>
    <%= f.check_box :tag_list, { multiple: true }, 'math', nil %>
  <% end %>

  ...
</div>
```

Also make sure that the JavaScript isn't called until the page has finished loading:

```
// application.js
$(function() {
  $(':checkbox').radiocheck();
});
```

Comment: I just tried this. It doesn't seem to work, I added $(':checkbox').radiocheck(); to my flat-ui-pro.min.js file and to my flatuipro.js file

Comment: Did it give you an error? Did *anything* change? We need some reference of what's going on to give you more help.

Comment: Sorry, in my console I get  Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function with the line $(':checkbox').radiocheck(); being highlighted. In my browser, the checkboxes are all still there with the same style, they lables are shifted over the the right.

Comment: That means the function `radiocheck()` hasn't been defined yet. Make sure you are adding the line at the *very end* of **all** of your javascript, i.e., at the bottom of `application.js`.

Comment: I did this and i'm still getting this message in my console: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: @KatieH Are you sure you're including the js file in `application.js`? Can you post the header of that file in your question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71404/discussion-between-jon-and-katie-h).

Answer (score 1):

You need the radiocheck js file:

You can download the js file: [`radiocheck.js`](https://github.com/designmodo/Flat-UI/blob/master/js/radiocheck.js)

Include `radiocheck.js` file in `app/assets/javascripts` folder.

Add this line in your `application.js` and the file will look like this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require flat-ui.min
//= require radiocheck
//= require_tree .

$(function(){
    $(':checkbox').radiocheck();
});
```

Comment: I just tried this. It doesn't seem to work, I added $(':checkbox').radiocheck(); to my flat-ui-pro.min.js file and to my flatuipro.js file

Comment: Updated my answer, can you check it now?

Comment: I did this and i'm still getting this message in my console: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: @Katie, then wrap the radiocheck invocation inside a document ready (solution updated).

Comment: @KatieH, got it, you need the radiocheck.js file. I have update my answer. :)